# Best performance comparison website or resource for .Net Web Applications?

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-applications, architecture

I am the .Net specialist in a consultancy with many difference flavors of developers using many different languages and frameworks. Because everyone is pretty much trying to push their own agendas with our different clients in terms of what technology to propose, I'm constantly finding myself in the classic arguments with them all about "why" .Net may be a better technology solution for a given clients requirements.

Often time here, the debate comes down to the issue of performance. Usually the areas that are argued about here consist of costs, maintainability, and performance. I have a hard time arguing about cost because in general open-source technologies are usually cheaper, and although and can usual put a good word in for .Net in terms of total cost of ownership (It seems to be pretty easy to convince people that .Net applications have relative low costs for maintainability if the application architecture has been thoughtfully designed), we will really only push .Net here if the client understands and is indifferent about the costs associated with Microsoft licensing. In terms of maintainability, like I mentioned before, the other developers here realize how much a difference it can make when an application is thoughtfully designed. I have had around 8 years of experience programming .Net solutions and I'm pretty confident in my ability to present to a client all the features and tool sets that .Net provides to give an application a long, and easy to maintain life span.

So again, what it usually boils down to is an argument over performance. Up until now, I have worked for companies that already used Microsoft development technologies to developer their applications so while I have *discussed* performance with others in the past I have never been a position where I have had to *convince* performance. My other co-workers are always boasting about these different website that they go to that show improved performance for open-source web applications. This all being said, what I would like to know from everybody here is where do you usually go to get your information about how may some .Net web applications have out performed other technologies?

Thanks in advance for the advice,

-Matt

Comment: Good God, Man.  That was verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the detail, though I must say I forgot your question at the end.  =)

Anyhow, this is something that has certainly been on my mind in the past.  There is always a conflict on what technology is the best.  We all know on each side you will find zealots, so it's quite difficult weeding out the facts.  Professionally, I've seen successes/disasters on both sides of the fence.

For you, since you have a vested interest in .NET.  I would showcase success stories, such as ... (insert whatever big name site you want)  Facebook, SO, etc.  I'd also find stories where things went wrong on the .NET side and pinpoint the reason.  Like you said, it is often poor implementation.  I don't know how many DailyWTF stories I've seen with ASP.NET sites behaving poorly but it gets traced back to 1) Poor design 2) Implementation 3) Coding.

Once you have a solid show case to justify the technology you can then of course talk about your own past experiences.  You need to qualify yourself as being able to avoid the same pitfalls that your stories exposed.

Answer (score 0):

.NET loses in performance against C/C++. In general, it will win over Python, Ruby, and PHP in baseline performance. The static typing tends translates into faster native code. (There are exceptions, such as Python's hand-tweaked set() performance being faster than HashSets in .NET)

The difference might come down to things like apache vs IIS (and their respective caching configurations), database architecture, etc. Features than can be misused or misunderstood (ViewStates and large GridViews, or using large numbers of hidden WebControls, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of application you are building I've found that performance is rarely an issue.  All the technologies out there can perform well enough.

When debating .net versus java/ruby/python etc I usually try to point out other benefits of .net.

There was this one time my boss asked me why .net instead of others?  He wanted to know because he could get a PHP programmer for cheap.  As part of the report we wrote a simple web application in 4 different languages and the .net app ran the fastest by far.  After that we solidified behind .net.  This was when .net was new so none of us really knew it well.  We came from ASP, PHP, Coldfusion and Java backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for .Net performance stories you can listen to [this dot net rocks show](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=666)